# Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number. What should I do now?

Tags: r, datetime, visualization, openair

I am trying to plot a summary plot for air pollution data but I'm facing this issue

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `date`. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `date`. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: `date`. 
4: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

My code:

```
gum <- read_xls("Gummidipoondi Daily average from 2018 to Sep.2021.xls") 
summaryPlot(gum)
```

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of your data i.e. `dput(head(gum, 20))`

Comment: According to the documentation `A data frame to be summarised. Must contain a date field and at least one other parameter.`  Based on the warning messages, it seems that you don't have the 'date' column in the dataset

Comment: there is a date column, but when I import the csv file into R the columns are in character format where it should be double. how can I fix this?